# Editing Bootstrap Variables with SASS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gulp, gruntjs, bootstrap-4

I develop an ASPNetCore2 Web application with VisualStudio2017. I try to override some styles from Bootstrap 4 beta.

- I've been importing Bootstrap from bower.
- I've create `gruntfile.js` for Grunt tasks
- I've create `gulpfile.js` for Gulp
- I've also create `compilerconfig.json` file for WebCompiler (mimification) In my `wwwroot\scss` folder, I've  :
- site.scss, which imports _custom (to use variables on some custom styles).

  ```
  @import "_custom.scss";
  // my variables, some has the same name that bootstrap variables, to override it
  $body-bg: $gray-100;
  //...
  $orange-900: darken($orange, 90%);

  html {
          body {
          //
          }
  }
  ```
- `_custom.scss` file where I've copy `_variables.scss` content and editing variables.
  I've this error : `"no mixin named -assert-ascending\n\nBacktrace:\n\t_custom.scss:334"`
- to solv this error, I add some lines in the top of file ; then, I've compile with grunt and gulp.

  ```
  @import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
  @import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
  @import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
  ```

In this case, my full bootstrap scss + my scss is correctly generated to one css file (with grunt and gulp). But variables are bootstrap variables, not mine.

- I've try to import all bootstrap scss files and compile with grunt and gulp. In this case, I've this error : `"Undefined variable: \"$alert-padding-y\".".` But `$alert-padding-y` is defined at line 874... in my `_custom.scss`  file.

Gruntfile.js :

```
    /// <binding />
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
        'use strict';

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

        grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

            // Sass
            sass: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true, // Create source map
                    outputStyle: 'compressed' // Minify output
                },
                dist: {
                    files: [
                      {
                          expand: true, // Recursive
                          cwd: "scss", // The startup directory
                          src: ["wwwroot/scss/site.scss"], // Source files//'wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/**/*.scss'
                          dest: "wwwroot/css/", // Destination
                          ext: ".css" // File extension 
                      }
                    ]
                }//, //files: {'wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/**/*.scss':'wwwroot/css/bootstrap.css'}
            },

            // Autoprefixer
            autoprefixer: {
                options: {
                    //browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
                    map: true // Update source map (creates one if it can't find an existing map)
                },

                // Prefix all files
                multiple_files: {
                    src: 'wwwroot/css/*.css'
                },
            },

            // Watch
            watch: {
                css: {
                    files: ['wwwroot/scss/site.scss'],//'wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/**/*.scss',//'wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/**/*.scss',
                    tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer'],
                    options: {
                        spawn: false
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        grunt.registerTask('dev', ['watch']);
        grunt.registerTask('prod', ['sass', 'autoprefixer']);
    };
    /*
    This file in the main entry point for defining grunt tasks and using grunt plugins.
    Click here to learn more. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513275&clcid=0x409

    module.exports = function (grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
        });
    };
    */
```

Gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
    fs = require("fs"),
    less = require("gulp-less"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass");


gulp.task('default', function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});

gulp.task("sass", function () {
    return gulp.src('wwwroot/scss/site.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/css'));
});
```

I don't want override css with another simple css file. I want to rebuild bootstrap with my variables, set "true" to "$enable-gradients" variable, set my colors to primary and secondary variables, etc.

For the moment, the only solution I found is to modify the file "_variables.scss"...

Comment: I'm getting the same error when trying to build bootstrap with gulp.  Did you solve it?

Comment: @wilsmex the only solution i've found is ... override original file "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss"  ...: / it works but if I need to upgrade ... you guess what i mean ;)